# Slamming the guy because his English wasn't perfect

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, alleged-abuse

If found this little gem in one of my Google searches:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745537/where-do-i-get-chrome-extension-samples

The question: i am new to create chrome extensions. where do i get extension samples with worked codes ? Thank you.

It was closed because: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, visit the help center.
If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question."

It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.
**It is extremely easy to tell what is being asked.**

This question is ambiguous, 
**Nothing could further from the truth.**

vague, 
**It might be brief and to the point, but not vague.**

incomplete, 
**Nope, he wants to know where some samples are.  That's it.**

overly broad, 
**If your looking for samples, or a broad sample, that might be contradictory. I was looking a sampling of extensions myself at the time.**

or rhetorical 
**not a chance**

and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. 
**Um sure, impossible for all us experts**

I like to make particular **acknowledgment to @apsillers and @Jamalx31** who just complete ignored this lunacy and answered the poor guy's question.

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.
**This seems be someone having difficulty with the language.  I wonder how that is going to work out**

Now fair criticism might include he could have done a Google search first.  It might hover be that he considers the Exchange to be the go to place for answers.  A question that should be answered here anyway.

**THE WHOLE THING CAME ACROSS AS BIGOTED**  As slamming the guy because his English wasn't perfect.  Nice.  So on a major search item people learn that this is the site to avoid asking questions unless you want to be the target of a bunch of arrogant bigots that may not answer your question anyway.

Well, unless your English is good.  Then welcome, ask away.

Comment: This is how it comes across, but It is a broad question, with many answers, so it did need to be closed.

Comment: I don't know about broad, but it I'd have flagged it as asking for a recommendation/favourite off-site resource.

Comment: I can see how you might have reached the conclusion in your post here, but when asking for a bit of understanding from others, might you not want to extend the same?

Comment: Andrew Barber - Well you raise a very good point there.  I tend to be extremely literal without intending to.  So I was reacting to exactly what I read in the closed reasons. ** I'm afraid I been working for a good 24hr and am a bit to zombied to respond to everything.  I certainly could have asked rather than going on a total rant.  ** You (and everyone) definitely have my sincere apologies.  Your right, in asking for understanding it's quite hypocritical to not give it.

Answer (score 19):

It has nothing to do with the guy's English writing skills.

It has more  to do with the fact that it's a shopping question, which is considered off topic on StackOverflow.

It's also too broad.  There are a lot of potential code samples that can be given to the OP that may or may not help him learn about chrome extensions.

---

If you really want to test this out, you can go to SO right now and ask a similar question, requesting some code samples on a specific platform.

If you do that I'll bet you that you'll get the same kind of response if not even **worse**

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't recommend taking the advice at the end of this answer. Just trust us; it won't end well! ;)